# how to find <a href> element in a webpage using Rselenium?

Tags: r, rselenium

I have the following tag in a webpage:

```
<a target="PARENT" href="/bin-din/WebOb/mom.ko/6/wo/asaksdaksjd
/5.1.5.5.33.23.23">View Data Set</a>
```

How can I lookup this element in Rselenium? For example if my current session is saved in remDr, what should I search for:

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement(??)
```

I need to search the element using it's display link (View Data Set) since the href link changes over time. 
Thanks much for your help

Comment: have you looked into the XML library? It has extensive capabilities to parse and search through the nodes of a webpage. I'd especially suggest looking into the xpath functions in the XML library.

Comment: @miles2know great thanks, I already tried some of them it just didn't work. Thank you though

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
library(XML)
fileUrl <- ("http:\\wherever you got your file")
doc <- htmlTreeParse(fileUrl, useInternal=T)
xpathSApply(doc, "//a[@href]", xmlGetAttr, "href")
```

Demonstration:

```
fileUrl <- "http://kimkardashianonline.org/"
doc <- htmlTreeParse(fileUrl, useInternal=T)
xpathSApply(doc, "//a[@href]", xmlGetAttr, "href")
[1] "http://kimkardashianonline.org/?page_id=2"                                        
[2] "http://www.kimkardashianonline.org/gallery/"                                      
[3] "http://www.kimkardashianonline.org/icons/"                                        
[4] "http://#"                                                                         
[5] "http://kimkardashianonline.org/?page_id=42"
```

Comment: thanks for your response. It works great if the links look like <a href="..... "</a> but how about if the html tags look like this: <a target="PARENT" href="...."</a>, what should I do in this case? How should I change your code to detect the links for these tags? Thanks a lot

Comment: Look at this link [Intro to XML](http://www.omegahat.org/RSXML/shortIntro.pdf). The second page has the code that we used and it has more ideas to replace `xmlGetAttr`. Like xmlName , xmlAttrs , xmlChildren and xmlValue

Comment: warning: my R Studio crashed when I tried `xmlChildren`.

Answer (score 2):

In the answer by @plafort the [@href] was not needed unless you knew ahead of time what you wanted to set the href attribute value to. So here is a general way forward. This works for this url request. Obviously '_blank' isn't what you'd want.

```
    library(XML)
    library(RCurl)
    gSite <- getURL("http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/target-html-attribute/") 
    sParse <- htmlParse(gSite)
    xpathSApply(sParse, "//a[@target='_blank']", xmlGetAttr, "href")
```

Comment: Thanks so much its working!!!! The only issue is that it's only showing the first <a target="PARENT"> tag in my html webpage, however, I have five more of these links in that page, how should I find a list containing all of them? Thanks much

Comment: humph...could you post a quick example of the tags you want to grab. The code above gets all of the hrefs for <a tags where target="_blank". Not sure why this wouldn't do the same in your case.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. your code is working on any html. Something is wrong on my side, I will try to figure it out myself, otherwise I will get back to you again. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, this solution solved my problem as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use : `webElem$getElementAttribute("href")`