# Get all the twitter links in a web page using RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium, xpath, rselenium, xpath-1.0

I am trying to collect URLs from a webpage with Rselenium, but getting InvalidSelector error

Use R 3.6.0 on Windows 10 PC, Rselenium 1.7.5 with Chrome webdriver (chromever="75.0.3770.8")

```
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"), chromever="75.0.3770.8")
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4567L, browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()

url <- "https://www.aph.gov.au/Senators_and_Members/Parliamentarian_Search_Results?q=&mem=1&par=1&gen=0&ps=96"
remDr$navigate(url)

tt <- remDr$findElements(using = "xpath", "//a[contains(@href,'http://twitter.com/')]/@href")
```

I expect to collect URLs to Twitter accounts of politicians listed.
Instead I am getting the next error:

Selenium message:

```
invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//a[contains(@href,'http://twitter.com/')]/@href" is: [object Attr]. It should be an element.
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.80)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-1', revision: 'd1d3728cae', time: '2019-04-24T16:15:24'
System info: host: 'ALEX-DELL-17', ip: '10.0.75.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Error:   Summary: InvalidSelector
     Detail: Argument was an invalid selector (e.g. XPath/CSS).
     class: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException
     Further Details: run errorDetails method

When I make a similar search for very specific element all works fine, example:

```
tt <- remDr$findElement(value = '//a[@href = "http://twitter.com/AlboMP"]')
```

then

```
tt$getElementAttribute('href')
```

returns me URL I need

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When I checked the site, there is no element with such xpath. Can you try it with css_selector or link text?

Comment: The code should look for all links to twitter, it suppose to find all URLs that include http://twitter.com  The bottom code with strict search condition (concrete twitter URL) works fine. Maybe the issue is with that soft xpath syntax, but I don't see what is wrong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't anything about R so I am posting an answer with python. As this post is about R, I learned some R basics and posting it too.

The easiest way to get the twitter URL is by iterating through all the URLs in the webpage and check if it contains the word 'twitter' in it.

In python (which works absolutely fine):

```
driver.get('https://www.aph.gov.au/Senators_and_Members/Parliamentarian_Search_Results?q=&mem=1&par=1&gen=0&ps=96')
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for link in links:
    if 'twitter' in link.get_attribute("href"):
        print(link.get_attribute("href")
```

Result:

> http://twitter.com/AlboMP http://twitter.com/SharonBirdMP
>   http://twitter.com/Bowenchris http://twitter.com/tony_burke
>   http://twitter.com/lindaburneymp http://twitter.com/Mark_Butler_MP
>   https://twitter.com/terrimbutler http://twitter.com/AnthonyByrne_MP
>   https://twitter.com/JEChalmers http://twitter.com/NickChampionMP
>   https://twitter.com/LMChesters http://twitter.com/JasonClareMP
>   https://twitter.com/SharonClaydon
>   https://www.twitter.com/LibbyCokerMP
>   https://twitter.com/JulieCollinsMP http://twitter.com/fitzhunter
>   http://twitter.com/stevegeorganas https://twitter.com/andrewjgiles
>   https://twitter.com/lukejgosling https://www.twitter.com/JulianHillMP 
>   http://twitter.com/stephenjonesalp https://twitter.com/gedkearney
>   https://twitter.com/MikeKellyofEM http://twitter.com/mattkeogh
>   http://twitter.com/PeterKhalilMP http://twitter.com/CatherineKingMP
>   https://twitter.com/MadeleineMHKing https://twitter.com/ALEIGHMP
>   https://twitter.com/RichardMarlesMP
>   https://twitter.com/brianmitchellmp
>   http://twitter.com/#!/RobMitchellMP
>   http://twitter.com/ShayneNeumannMP https://twitter.com/ClareONeilMP
>   http://twitter.com/JulieOwensMP
>   http://www.twitter.com/GrahamPerrettMP
>   http://twitter.com/tanya_plibersek http://twitter.com/AmandaRishworth 
>   http://twitter.com/MRowlandMP https://twitter.com/JoanneRyanLalor
>   http://twitter.com/billshortenmp http://www.twitter.com/annewerriwa
>   http://www.twitter.com/stemplemanmp
>   https://twitter.com/MThistlethwaite
>   http://twitter.com/MariaVamvakinou https://twitter.com/TimWattsMP
>   https://twitter.com/joshwilsonmp

In R: (This may be wrong but you can get an idea)

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
library(RSelenium)
url <- "https://www.aph.gov.au/Senators_and_Members/Parliamentarian_Search_Results?q=&mem=1&par=1&gen=0&ps=96"
doc <- getURL(url)
parser <- htmlParse(doc)
links <- xpathSApply(parser, "//a[@href]", xmlGetAttr, "href")
for(link in links){
    if(grepl("twitter", link)){
        print(link)
    }
}
```

I don't even know if this code will work. But the idea is to get all the URLs in a page, iterate over it and check if the word twitter is in it.
My answer is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29866339/9368703)

Comment: Thanks @Prasanth! That approach, with  "xpathSApply(parser, "//a[@href]", xmlGetAttr, "href")" works to find all URLs on the page, which indeed then can be filtered to include only a subset matching criteria.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//a[contains(@href,'http://twitter.com/')]/@href" is: [object Attr]. It should be an element.
```

......implies that your XPath expression was not a valid one.

The [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expression:

```
//a[contains(@href,'http://twitter.com/')]/@href
```

doesn't return an element. It would return a `[object Attr]`. While this was acceptable using `Selenium RC` but the methods of WebDriver's *WebElement* interface requires an element object, not just any DOM node object.

To sum it up, [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) still doesn't supports this format. and to fix the issue, you'd need to change the HTML markup to wrap the text node inside an element, like a .

---

### Solution

To fix this issue you need to use `findElements` and create a *List*:

```
findElements(value = '//a[@href = "http://twitter.com/AlboMP"]')
```

Now, you can iterate over the *List* and using `getElementAttribute('href')` method you can extract the URLs.

---

### Reference

[InvalidSelectorError: The result of the xpath expression is: [object Text]](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5459)

Comment: Hi Debanjan, thanks for your answer.
<br>
I know that the code 
`
findElements(value = '//a[@href = "http://twitter.com/AlboMP"]')
`
works. 
<br>
However it doesn't solve my task - I need to extract URLs that I don't know exactly, but matching certain pattern, namely contain 'twitter.com' in URL. Hence I use the expression with 'contain'.
<br>
The code above returns just one URL.

Comment: @Alex The error which you were seeing `invalid selector` and the task to _extract URLs_ are completely two different aspects. In this answer I have provided you the canonical answer on how to avoid the `invalid selector` error.

Comment: Your answer effectively duplicates the final part of my question, I already new that the code findElements(value = '//a[@href = "http://twitter.com/AlboMP"]') worked

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe a little late. But your solution may be taking the vector of links in this way:

links=RemDr$findElements(value = "//*[contains(@href, 'https://www.twitter.com/')]")