# I want to right click on a file link to copy the link address using RSelenium

Tags: html, r

I want to right click on the link named 'CSV Summary' just to copy the link address of that CSV file because on clicking the link it starts downloading the file directly which I don't want.
Attached is the code which I used to reach that page showing CSV summary, the link address of which I need to copy. [code used](https://github.com/hafiza12345/test-BepiPred/blob/main/test%20bepipred.R)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GVX0.jpg)

Comment: Use `findElement` to get the reference to the CSV Summary Link Then use `getElementAttribute` to get the `href=` attribute for that link (that's where the address is stored). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855009/how-to-find-a-href-element-in-a-webpage-using-rselenium

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you can call on their JSON source to get the data

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

"https://services.healthtech.dtu.dk/services/BepiPred-2.0/tmp/630F1ABF0000500259861910/results.json" %>% 
  request() %>% 
  req_perform() %>%  
  resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE)
```

If you want to download the CSV, there is link embedded in the JSON

```
"https://services.healthtech.dtu.dk/services/BepiPred-2.0/tmp/630F1ABF0000500259861910/results.json" %>% 
  request() %>% 
  req_perform() %>%  
  resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE) %>% 
  .$csv_summary %>%  
  str_c("https://services.healthtech.dtu.dk", .) %>%  
  download.file(url = .,
                destfile = "heatlh.csv", 
                mode = "wb")
```